# Constraints on GARCH parameters

Tags: estimation, garch

I have been working on a manual implementation of ARMA GARCH (1,1) with:
$$\sigma_{t}^2 = \omega + \alpha\epsilon_{t-1}^2 + \beta\sigma_{t-1}^2$$

and estimating parameters through MLE. However, my constant term in GARCH, $\omega$, seems to grow without bound as the optimization proceeds. Is there any sort of constraint on the GARCH parameters other than they must all be non-negative and that $\alpha + \beta < 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to ensure that the conditional variance is always non-negative you have the restrictions $\omega>0$, $\alpha \geq 0$ and $\beta\geq 0$. Also for a weakly stationary process you need have $\alpha+\beta<1$. There are other constrains in order to ensure that higher moments exist. For example, assuming normal distributed innovations, you need the parameter restriction $3\alpha^2+2\alpha\beta+\beta^2<1$ for a finite fourth moment. However, this should not effect your estimation process, since for many GARCH models higher moments do not exist, when these models are estimated using real financial data. I assume there may be an error in your code, but this is difficult to answer without without seeing the code.

Regards

Comment: Thank you very much! At the moment I am feeding my ARMA residuals into GARCH and using that as data. I set $\sigma_0 = \text{Var}(\{\epsilon_i\})$ as an initial guess and march ahead using the GARCH equations, including the first four constraints you mentioned. Since $\epsilon_i = \sigma_i z_i$ I evaluate $\frac{\epsilon_i}{\sigma_i}$ at the PDF to obtain a probability. This is a rough outline for how I am carrying out my GARCH MLE. Is any of this incorrect? Currently I have gotten the code to run by setting an arbitrary constraint that $\omega \leq 1$.

Comment: @CBBAM, you should rather set $\sigma_0^2$, not $\sigma_0$ to be the variance of $\epsilon$. But perhaps this was just a typo.

Comment: @RichardHardy How big of an impact would that change make? At the moment I have it set as the variance of $\{\epsilon_i\}$. I would rerun my code but due to all the optimization it takes quite a bit of time (2-3 days to complete).

Comment: @CBBAM, I think it can make a big change. It might even be the root of the problem you are describing in your question.

Comment: @RichardHardy I changed $\sigma_0^2$ to zero and I'm still getting my constant term to increase without bound.

Comment: @CBBAM, zero is an impossible value, so it might be as bad as the one you had before. Try setting it to the unconditional variance of the error process.

Comment: @RichardHardy So far from my trials I obtain that $\omega \in [7,13]$, $\alpha$ is almost always nearly 0, and $\beta$ is almost always nearly 1. These values seem odd, though I am inexperienced with ARMA GARCH. My overall log likelihood per iteration is between 800-900. Are these values reasonable?

Comment: @CBBAM From my experience (of course this depends on the time series used), the value of $\omega$ seems to be too large.  For example, calculate $\frac{\omega}{1-(\alpha+\beta)}$, which is the unconditional variance of the process. You should get a strange value for that. Which optimization algorithm do you use ? I simply use BHHH and this works quite well in most cases.

Comment: @Jonas_Dim I do indeed get a very strange value when I calculate the unconditional variance. I am currently using the NLOPT library with the COBYLA algorithm. After some debugging I also noticed my forecasting variance is about 4000-5000, which is huge. Maybe the problem isn't in the optimization but in my GARCH formulation?